Apps Script OAuth2 Library Dropping Scopes
Edit: solved, it wound up fixing itself overnight. Ran the same code today and it worked as expected. The service account was still pretty new, so perhaps some jobs hadn't run yet to finish the setup. Still shows no scopes when I log after setting up the service, but the call is working, so they have to be there. I've seen some desynchronization with logging in apps script before, so I'm going to chalk it up to that unless someone has a better insight.
Experimenting with using gcp service accounts to query gemini from a spreadsheet via the OAuth2 library. Using the example from the Google Workspace Installable Triggers guide.
function test() {
  const service = OAuth2.createService(<ServiceName>)
      .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
      .setPrivateKey(<serviceAccountPrivateKey>)
      .setClientId(<serviceAccountAddress>)
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
      .setScope([
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
      ]);

  console.log('access: ', service.hasAccess(), 'scopes: ', service.scope);

  if (!service.hasAccess()) {
    console.error('Authentication error: ', service.getLastError());
    return;
  }


  const options = {
    method: "post",
    contentType: 'application/json',   
    headers: {
     Authorization: `Bearer ${service.getAccessToken()}`,
    },
    payload: JSON.stringify({...})
  };

  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(<url>, options);
  ...
}

When I run it, the log shows access:  true scopes:  undefined, and I get the following error:
Exception: Request failed for <url> returned code 403. Truncated server response: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details":... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

I've tried copying the setScopes function out of the OAuth2 repo and running it on my scope array to make sure I wasn't just doing the input wrong, and it was properly generating a space-delimited list of scopes. Tried passing a space-delimited list instead of an array, still comes back undefined. As best as I've been able to tell, the code is largely the same as whats found in the example I linked above.
The service appears to be successfully getting a token, but something is happening to the scopes. Any insight is appreciated.

Did you add those scopes in appscript.json ???


setScope() accepts a space concatenated string of scopes - not a list. 2) Remove setClientId() which is not used for service accounts. 3) Add .setIssuer(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL).


@JohnHanley

setScope should be able to take string array, according to the jsdoc and apparent implementation. Seems to be working fine for me now.
Cool. Removed, seems good. Any idea why they include it in the docs?
The service seems to be working without setIssuer, and they don't really go into it in the docs. Can you elaborate on what the issuer prop does?


You're right. My answer is incorrect and therefore I deleted it.

Client ID and Secret ID are related to OAuth clients. Service accounts use an RSA private key, key ID, and email address. However, only the private key is required. I could not find the library you were using previously. Almost all require a space-separated string. What change did you make to get this working? The requirements are more strict when you start using delegation.

Note: I am not familiar with the internals of the auth client library you are using. I am very familiar with the low-level details of what is required. To me, the example looks like a mistake.
